# How to debug javascript file on Firefox OS device

Tags: javascript, firefox-os

I want to edit a  script file  of Firefox OS device. But I do not know how ?  When I use the console  There's no option for editing . SO my question is how can I debug and edit the script file ?

Comment: How did you create the file originally?

Comment: no I did not create the file . I want to debug the certified app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For live debugging, you can run use the about:app-manager page inside the Firefox browser. You can install the ADB (Android Debug Brdige) to connect the FirefoxOS device with the Browser:

```
// install ADB

// Linux
apt-get install android-tools-adb

// OSX
brew install android-platform-tools
```

Then you can connect to your device using ADB commands:

```
// connect to your device / change IP
adb connect 192.168.1.5

// connect as root
adb root

// get a shell to your device, Ctrl-D will quit
adb shell

// enable port forwarding to use app-manager in your Desktop Firefox browser
adb forward tcp:6000 localfilesystem:/data/local/debugger-socket // or ADB Helper

// get the log output
adb logcat
```

When connected you, should be able connect the app-manager with your device inside your Desktop Firefox browser. Then you can run the App you want to live debug. You get an inspector, console and debugger (Firefox dev tools) just like you would get for every other website.

[image: see all installed apps]

[image: dev tools]

When you need to persist the changes, you need to save the desired files locally and use adb pull/push to trasmit the files from and back to the devicce:

```
adb pull /system/b2g/webapps/browser.gaiamobile.org/application.zip
adb push application.zip /system/b2g/webapps/browser.gaiamobile.org/application.zip
```

Comment: when I try to connect my device. It says unable to connect. Any solution for that? Moreover when I run `adb shell` command It shows  `error:more than one device and emulator`.

Comment: Ok I fix that issue. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

You may download Firefox Developer edition browser for your desktop/pc then go to webIDE from the setting and download simulator of the Firefox OS.Go to webIDE, you can choose the any downloaded app in the simulator for the debug.

To download Firefox developer edition browser go to  : https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/#aurora

Comment: But you can edit script this way :( you can only change html css

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can debug certified apps on the phone if you have enabled DevTools restricted privileges using the toolbar menu Runtime->Runtime Info when you are connected to the device.  You can not edit the JavaScript files though.  In order to do this, you need to check out Gaia and flash it to your phone.  You could also probably use adb pull/push to replace the current system apps as well.  If you want to checkout Gaia see this page:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Developing_Gaia
source for the apps is here:
https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/tree/master/apps