# No Device Found Firefox OS App Manager

Tags: firefox, firefox-os, app-manager

I am trying to developing an app in Firefox OS, but my device can't found in App Manager. How do I fix this? Thanks for the response!

Comment: What is your operating system ?

Answer (score 0):

Let me refer to my previous answer here: [How to debug javascript file on Firefox OS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27691059/how-to-debug-javascript-file-on-firefox-os-device)

You need to install ADB (Android Debug Bridge) and very important config the port forwarding:

```
// enable port forwarding to use app-manager in your Desktop Firefox browser
adb forward tcp:6000 localfilesystem:/data/local/debugger-socket // or ADB Helper
```

You also need to enable the debugging in the Settings menu on your device.